SQL Server statistics logical reads negative number
I am trying to understand and analyse a CPU intensive select query in SQL Server, however, I see something strange which is a negative number as logical reads. I wonder if it is a mathematical overflow issue or it is a meaningful number.
I'm using:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU29-GDR) (KB5046860) - 15.0.4410.1 (X64)



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. The above image should be converted to a markdown table.
